# How to get average of a column using rust diesel?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to get the average value of a column using rust diesel but am stuck with the type error.

Error:

```
the trait bound `f64: FromSql<Numeric, _>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `FromSql<A, DB>`:
  <f32 as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Float, DB>>
  <f64 as FromSql<Double, DB>>
  <i16 as FromSql<SmallInt, DB>>
  <i32 as FromSql<Integer, DB>>
  <i64 as FromSql<BigInt, DB>>
  <u32 as FromSql<Oid, Pg>>
required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<Numeric, _>` for `f64`
```

Code:

```
   let new_avg: Option<f64> = fruits
                .select(avg(weight))
                .filter(fruit_name.eq(&fruit_name))
                .get_result::<Option<f64>>(&self.postgres.get().unwrap())
                .unwrap();
```

Comment: Besides the point of the question, as in the (now deleted) previous question: You should never, ever represent currencies (e.g. prices, salaries) as a floating-pointer number, even temporarily. The result **will** be wrong and there is **no** way to fix it. Contemplate that [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=96f747cc6f3210471e3536548e96d8c5) program will panic. Do. Not. Use. A. Float.

Comment: I am not sure if this is it, but you are using `Option`, while `get_results` retursn `Err(...)` on 0 rows. So I think this code snippet should return an `f64`.

However what actually could go on that using `f64` or `f32` highly depends on the column type, so can you please share the table definition? Is the field a Double or a Float? If it is Numeric (what it looks like), you must return a `BigDecimal`, as that's what Numeric maps to.

Comment: This question is missing important details in the form of a minimal reproducible example. Especially information about the used diesel + rustc version, your schema and any referenced types (e.g. `&self`) are missing. This makes it hard for others to understand, reproduce and answer such questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to cast type Numeric from postgres to f64 in Rust, which does not have implementation.

I tried to reproduce your case so I created table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value NUMERIC NOT NULL
)
```

for which diesel generated for me this in schemas:

```
table! {
    fruits (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        value -> Numeric,
    }
}
```

and in models I created Fruit:

```
#[derive(Queryable, Debug)]
pub struct Fruit {
    pub id: i32,
    pub value: f64
}
```

Right now when I try to run this:

```
let results = fruits.load::<Fruit>(&pg_connection).expect("");
```

I'm getting the same error as you which we can solve in few ways.

**If you want to keep type f64 in Rust** then you can change in table creation that value should have type *DOUBLE PRECISION* which after running diesel migration will generate Float8 type in schema which has it's implementation mentioned in error:

```
= help: the following implementations were found:
    <f64 as FromSql<Double, DB>>
```

**If you want to keep type Numeric in postgres table** you can try using *bigecimal::BigDecimal* or *diesel::pg::data_types::PgNumeric* as type of value in Fruit struct since there is also implementation for casting Numeric to PgNumeric.

**If you want to keep both** you probably have to implement it on you own